# Parralax with scroll control in Figma

Tags: figma, figma-plugin

Here's the animation I'd like to prototype with figma.
https://urlz.fr/oigz
I know we have smart animate to start with.
But here I want to control the animation (reveal and hide image) with progressive drag control. I don't want all the animation (reveal and hide) to be executed on the drag, but if a drag downwards progressively, the image is progressively hidden and uncovered if drag upwards.
Is this possible with figma alone, or is there a plugin to achieve this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You mean parallax?